# Turn ion-toggle change event into a mouseup mousedown button click

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, phonegap

I am trying to create a button that when pressed turns it on and when let go turns it off similar to a `mouseup` and `mousedown` event.
I got an example running using ionic and want to implement the following (`onPowerSwitchChange`) with a button such as:

```
<button ion-button round large outline 
(click)="onPowerSwitchChange(event)">Button</button>`
```

From this (original):

```
<ion-item>
<ion-label>Power</ion-label>
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="power" (ionChange)="onPowerSwitchChange($event);">
</ion-toggle>
</ion-item>`
```

I'm thinking that I need to modify the .ts to implement a sort of push button switch for the light.

Ts:

```
onPowerSwitchChange(event) {
    console.log('onPowerSwitchChange');
    let value = this.power ? 1 : 0;
    let buffer = new Uint8Array([value]).buffer;
    console.log('Power Switch Property ' + this.power);
    this.ble.write(this.peripheral.id, LIGHTBULB_SERVICE, SWITCH_CHARACTERISTIC, buffer).then(
      () => this.setStatus('Light is ' + (this.power ? 'on' : 'off')),
      e => this.showAlert('Unexpected Error', 'Error updating power switch')
    );
```

Any suggestions or direction to solving this problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

is [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/ekjIurMbrcJIms1EW6i7?) what you had in mind?

you can style the button conditionally with ngStyle directive to differentiate between toggled and released state.

```
  <button ion-button [ngClass]="{'toggled':buttonActivated}" (click)="toggleButton()">
      <span *ngIf="!buttonActivated">Turn ON</span>
      <span *ngIf="buttonActivated">Turn OFF</span>
    </button>
```

in the class just set the buttonActivated variable properly

```
export class HomePage {

  appName = 'Ionic App';
  buttonActivated = false;
  constructor(public navController: NavController) { }
  toggleButton(){
    this.buttonActivated = !this.buttonActivated;
  }
}
```